# Send email via Hotmail to gmail

Tags: c#

I'm working on app, which sends emails. I've created account on hotmail. 
This is my code:

```
try
{
    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        var mailAddressTo = new MailAddress(emailType.EmailAddress);
        var mailAddressFrom = new MailAddress("id");
        using (var mailMessage = new MailMessage(mailAddressFrom, mailAddressTo))
        {
            smtpClient.Host = "smtp.live.com";
            smtpClient.Port = 587;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("id@hotmail.com", "pass");
            mailMessage.Subject = emailType.EmailSubject;               
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{}
```

But it gives me exception:

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.3.4 Requested action not taken; We noticed some unusual activity in your Hotmail account. To help protect you, we've temporarily blocked your account.

I don't wanna use Gmail, because it requires phone number. How can i do that with hotmail?
thanks

Comment: Given the error message, clearly looks like you can't do this with Hotmail

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been marked down...  I had the same issue and this helped me to resolve it.

Comment: Why `mailAddressFrom` is only `id` and not full email address?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this, it works for me.

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("email@hotmail.com");
mail.To.Add("ToGmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Your Sub";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
string htmlBody;
htmlBody = "HTML code";
mail.Body = htmlBody;
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@hotmail.com", "YourPassword");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: I use account xxx@outlook.es but I get error: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated. I login using live.com, and all is OK.